# $.when not waiting for Jstree open function to finish

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a jstree tree that all the tree items are loaded using ajax calls to my server to populate the children of each folder.  I am trying to build a function that will drill down through the tree and select a child depending on what I pass into the function.  I am currently using the following function to do this, but my $.when(...).done(...) function is not waiting for the open to occur and then can't load any children below it.

```
function openNodes(tree, nodesToOpenRaw, selectedNode) {
    var treeObj = $(tree);
    treeObj.one('loaded.jstree', function() {
        openNodesRaw(treeObj, nodesToOpenRaw, selectedNode);
    });
}

function openNodesRaw(tree, nodesToOpen, selectedNode) {
    if (tree.jstree('is_open', nodesToOpen[0])) {
        goToNextNode(tree, nodesToOpen, selectedNode);
    } else {
        $.when(tree.jstree("open_node", nodesToOpen[0])).done(function () {
            if (nodesToOpen[0] == null) {
                goToNextNode(tree, nodesToOpen, selectedNode);
                return;
            }
            goToNextNode(tree, nodesToOpen, selectedNode);
        });
    }
}

function goToNextNode(tree, nodesToOpen, selectedNode) {
    if (nodesToOpen.length > 0 && Object.prototype.toString.call(nodesToOpen) === '[object Array]') {
        var newNodesToOpen = nodesToOpen.slice(0);
        newNodesToOpen.shift();
        openNodesRaw(tree, newNodesToOpen, selectedNode);
    } else {
        tree.jstree("select_node", selectedNode, true);
        tree.unbind('ajaxSuccess');
    }
}
```

Why is the $.when function waiting for the ajax call of tree.jstree("open_node",....) to finish before continuing on with the next function?

Comment: What `tree.jstree()` function returns?

Comment: That is a really good question.  I looked through the documentation and couldn't really find any reference to what it returned.  http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core

Comment: `console.log()` the call and see

Comment: The following code (var test = tree.jstree("open_node", nodesToOpen[0]);
        console.log(test);) returns [<div>, context: #document, selector: "#navigation"]
0: <div>
context: #document
length: 1
selector: "#navigation"
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: Well, I looked at the sources and it just returns the jstree object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$.when()` expects its arguments to be jQuery [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Presumably `tree.jstree()` returns something else.

Comment: so how can I write a function that calls tree.jstree() and returns a $.Deffered when the call to tree.jstree() is done?

Comment: @PlTaylor: "when the call to tree.jstree() is done?" - is the call asynchronous?

Comment: The call to tree.jstree() opens a node in the tree and populates it with the info from an ajax call that is fired.  So I believe the entire thing is async due to the ajax call.

Comment: @PlTaylor: no, entire thing is synchronous. You need to bind to jstree events